# When working with batches via the Dataset API in Tensorflow what is the recommended way to perform index lookups in dictionary?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am currently going about refactoring existing code over to the newer TF Dataset API. In our current process we populate a standard python dictionary with product ids to classification ids.

Now I have moved over our images/paths to a TF Dataset and then using tf.string_split I extract various information from the filename itself. One of them being the product_id. At this point the product_id is a tf tensor which I am unable to perform a lookup using our previous means via "**if product_id in products_to_class**" because I now have a tensor and I can't perform a search via the standard dictionary.

So I am using this project as a way to learn how to increase performance. So I wanted to know what the "best/recommended" approach is to take here when working with the tf Dataset API batches.  Do I convert the product_id to a string and just perform the lookup via the current if check above or do I now go about converting the products_to_class dictionary to another data structure such as another Dataset and perform the lookup using tensors throughout?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Small example of what I have currently is:

```py
prod_to_class = {'12345': 0, '67890': 1}

#Below logic is in a mapped function used on a TF.Dataset
def _parse_fn(filename, label)
  core_file = tf.string_split([filename], '\\').values[-1]
  product_id = tf.string_split([core_file], ".").values[0]

  #unable to perform below because product_id is now a tensor and
  #products_to_class is a python dictionary
  if product_id in products_to_class:
    label = products_to_class[product_id]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in TensorFlow mechanism for doing this is to use a [`tf.contrib.lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup) table. For example, if you have a list of string keys that you want to map to dense integers, you can define the following outside your `_parse_fn()`:

```
# This constructor creates a lookup table that implicitly maps each string in the
# argument to its index in the list (e.g. '67890' -> 1).
products_to_class = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(['12345', '67890'])
```

...and then use [`products_to_class.lookup()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/LookupInterface#lookup) in your `_parse_fn()`.

```
def _parse_fn(filename, label):
  core_file = tf.string_split([filename], '\\').values[-1]
  product_id = tf.string_split([core_file], ".").values[0]

  # Returns a `tf.Tensor` that corresponds to the value associated with 
  # `product_id` in the `products_to_class` table.
  label = products_to_class.lookup(product_id)

  # ...
```

Note that this places two additional constraints on your program:

1. You must use `Dataset.make_initializable_iterator()` instead of `Dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()`.
2. You must call `sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())` before starting to consume elements from the input pipeline.

Both of these will be handled for you if you use the high-level `tf.estimator` API and return the `tf.data.Dataset` from your `input_fn`.

Comment: Thank you greatly mrry for this!  You have helped me countless times on SO...you need to setup a crypto tip jar on here :)  Thanks again!